# Changing the color of the stars and display half star rating using AngularUI Star Rating

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI star rating, but I would like to perform the following 2 items.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

1. I would like change the color of the selected star ("stateOn: glyphicon-star') to yellow.  Is there a way to do that?
2. I also would like to display half star as well. For example, I want to display 3 1/2 stars.  Can you please tell me how to do that?

**Here is the rating tags for the star rating in AngularUI:**

```
<rating value="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" </rating>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Half stars will take some changes to the logic and possibly the CSS (I imagine something like if it has a remainder after drawing the number of stars it should for the floored value then draw a star in a container with half the width and no overflow, or maybe just make a half star icon).  The color you can simply override in your own CSS like

```
.glyphicon-star, .glyphicon-star-empty {
  color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for a more concrete answer.  After re-read your answer a couple of times, I think I know what to do for the 1/2 star rating.  I was able to use css class like you said to do change the star's color.

Comment: SO isn't a place to ask someone else to do work for you.  It's a place to ask for help when you've done some work.  Given there wasn't any code provided to work on I gave the best answer to keep you moving forward I could, thanks for accepting.  In the future please provide a plunkr showing what you're working on and you'll get more help.

Comment: Just to complete the hole stuff if you want some size change you can add font-size: 30px; as well. :) Great answer in fact!

Answer (score 0):

```
.glyphicon-star : before, .glyphicon-star-empty: before{
  color:yellow;
}
```

This will also result into the same